# Generating java from rpc wsdl

Tags: maven, rpc, wsdl2java

I have a [pom](http://bit.ly/SjMwfc) which generates some java code from an RPC wsdl. The problem is that the code is never generated.

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>axistools-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.4</version>
<configuration>
  <sourceDirectory>src/main/resources</sourceDirectory>
  <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated/rpc</outputDirectory>
  <packageSpace>com.company.wsdl</packageSpace>
  <testCases>false</testCases>
  <serverSide>true</serverSide>
  <subPackageByFileName>false</subPackageByFileName>
</configuration>
<executions>
  <execution>
    <goals>
      <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
    </goals>
  </execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
```

Any ideas as to why this isnt generating the java code?

Comment: Fixed. I presumed i could do: **mvn clean install** but infact i needed to do:

**mvn axistools:wsdl2java**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After taken a look into your pom I realized your problem. It's not related to calling mvn its based on the configuration you made.

You have configured the axistools-maven-plugin in the pluginManagement area. In this case you need to do this in the build area like this:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>axistools-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.4</version>
      <configuration>
       ..
      </configuration>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <goals>
           <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
  ...
</build>
```

instead of:

```
<build>
 <pluginManagement>
   <plugins>
    ...
  </plugins>
 </pluginManagement>
  ...
</build>
```

If you configure it correctly you can use mvn clean package or mvn clean install instead of calling mvn axistools:wsdl2java ...